# How determine path in vb net for a text file then modify some lines inside

Tags: vb.net, variables, directory, path

I have to modify a text file than can be located either in c:\folder\test.txt or in c:\folder1\test.txt
I tried this:
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\Folder") and I can determine where the file is located.

Right now I have this line to modify the test.txt because I know is located on c:\folder

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("c:\folder\test.txt")
    fileContents = Replace(fileContents, "true", "false")
```

How can I do this automatically so when I open the application the path will change automatically based on where the test file is located then all the selections using buttons I have to do will be based on the actual path where test.txt is located.
Basically I have buttons assigned to change different lines located in test.txt

Thank you.

Comment: `path will change automatically based on where the test file is located` - are we taking about scanning the entire drive (drives?) of the computer for any file named `test.txt`? What if there are three thousand of them?

Comment: @GSerg I understood it as it's either in `c:\folder` or `c:\folder1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment,

> I have to modify a text file than can be located either in c:\folder\test.txt or in c:\folder1\test.txt

it's either in one path or the other. Check for the path to the file when your application starts

```vb
Private Const PATH_0 = "c:\folder\test.txt"
Private Const PATH_1 = "c:\folder1\test.txt"
Private pathToRead As String

Private Sub SandboxForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If File.Exists(PATH_0) Then
        pathToRead = PATH_0
    ElseIf File.Exists(PATH_1) Then
        pathToRead = PATH_1
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("File not found!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Later, you already know the path so just use it

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fileContents = Replace(File.ReadAllText(pathToRead), "true", "false")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was working on the code with the instructions provided and everything is fine except this. I have this line that creates a ip.txt in a folder.    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C arp -a> c:\folder\ip.txt") This will create a file, however when I implemented the path is not working anymore. Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C arp -a> pathToRead"). I tried different things but no luck so far. Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/C arp -a > ""{filePath}"""). Appreciate any guidance you may give.

Comment: @user8967715 That's a new question - see how code doesn't format in comments? I think I have answered your question above. If so, accept it and make a new question.